# React server side render: Cannot find module style-loader css-loader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to make server side render for my react web app.

In my React Component im trying too add following import:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Node return following error (I run through babel-node):

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '!style-loader!css-loader!font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/project/client/js/components/app.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at loader (D:\project\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\project\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Webpack can build it successfully.

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const CSSModulesLoader = [
  'css?sourceMap&-minimize',
  'modules',
  'importLoaders=1',
  'localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
].join('&');

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', CSSModulesLoader]
      }, {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff'
      }, {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

How to fix that error?

And other question is how to know the environment is not browser and best way to use server side render with module use variable like window (in my case is https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/reapop it return error: window is not define)?

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Should be like :

```
import 'path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

There is no need of `!style-loader!css-loader!` while importing css.

Comment: It return SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)